# Are two planes parallel when their direction vector is equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

The vectors topic is getting really confusing and googling ispretty much useless since all the answers I've found are really complex.

are these two fictious planes below parallel?

Plane alpha:$r(xi +yj +zk)=10$
Plane beta : $r(xi +yj +zk)=15$

Edit: isnt the general equation for a plane $r(xi+yi+zk)=c$ ?

Comment: Is $r$ a vector representing a general point on your plane?

Comment: yes its a general point

Comment: two planes are parallel if the direction vectors are linear dependend

Comment: And clearly equal vectors are linearly dependent with a constant of 1.

Comment: what do you mean Dr. Graubner?

Comment: @MadMathWiz: Your condition (equal) is sufficient but not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two planes are said to be parallel when their normal vectors are parallel. And two vectors are said to be parallel if their cross product is zero.

In other words, the direction cosines of the normal vectors are proportional if they are parallel.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The general equation for a plane works like this: Let $\textbf{r}$ be a general point on the plane, $\textbf{a}$ any fixed point on the plane and $\textbf{n}$ any vector perpendicular to the plane (n for normal). Then $\textbf{r}-\textbf{a}$ is always a vector parallel to the plane (or $\textbf{0}$). The dot product of perpendicular vectors is always $0$, that is why we have $$(\textbf{r}-\textbf{a})\cdot\textbf{n}=0.$$
Now, if you think about it, in your two examples, your $\textbf{n}$ vectors are both $x\textbf{i}+y\textbf{j}+z\textbf{k}$. If two planes have equal normal vectors then they are parallel (this bit you'll have to close your eyes and think about).

Addendum: To answer your last point, yes, $(\textbf{r}-\textbf{a})\cdot\textbf{n}=0$ can be rearranged to give $\textbf{r}\cdot\textbf{n}=\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{n}$, i.e. $\textbf{r}\cdot\textbf{n}=c$, say.